# Local account trying to login to a NAS, without asking

Tags: windows, network-shares

I'm working in a factory where we have a bunch of Windows 10 machines with nearly identical configuration (just related to which machines they talk to).  These machines do not have access to the Internet and have local accounts.

These machines have a script that periodically does a "net use" to map to a NAS, copies some files, then deletes the map.  The username it uses is different than the local user name.

However, on two machines, I see lots of errors on the NAS that the local account on the PC is trying to mount a network share on the NAS and failing (this user doesn't exist on the NAS).   These can be 50 attempts per minute.  The NAS logs don't show what share is being tried.

I'm unable to figure out why these two machines are doing this and none of the others are.

There are not any mapped drives on these machines and there are not any credentials in Credential Manager.   I can't think of any other configurable items that might cause this.

Any suggestions as to where else to look?